# discord.py Breaking news function limiting characters in a string

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering how I can make a certain limit of characters for a string. In this case I want to make 43 characters the maximum amount of characters for the bot the draw on the image.

```
@client.command(aliases=["news"])
async def breakingnews(ctx, *, text = None):
  if text == None:
    await ctx.send("Enter some text. (i.e p/breakingnews dragons are taking over phoenix territory)")
  elif len(text) > 43:
    await ctx.send("You can only put 43 characters max.")
    return
  else:
    news = Image.open("news.jpg")
    white = Image.open("newswhite.jpg")
    font = ImageFont.truetype("Arimo.ttf", 30)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(news)
    news.paste(white, (45, 374))
    draw.text((49, 380), text=text, font=font, fill=(0,0,0))
    news.save("news.jpg")
    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("news.jpg"))
```

Comment: what's the issue with your code?

Comment: You should describe the problem and of course debug it.

Answer (score -1):

You've got it mixed up.

```
elif len(text) <= 43:
    await ctx.send("You can only put 43 characters max.")
    return
```

You need to make it less than.

Comment: When I tried to do that, It resulted in the same problem (https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/805189077589557258/834211077558239252/news.jpg)

Comment: you should print text and len of text. Tell me what you get